# Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms after upgrading targetSdkVersion to 31 React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, sdk, android-13

After upgrading target sdk version to 31, I am seeing frequent crash in the application live on play store. Not receiving the same errors while testing. Seeing the crash only in samsung devices with android 13. Below are the logs for two errors received on Sentry.

```
io.sentry.android.core.ApplicationNotResponding: Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms.
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.notifyNativeAllocationsInternal(VMRuntime.java)
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.notifyNativeAllocation(VMRuntime.java:701)
at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:316)
at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:264)
at android.graphics.text.LineBreaker.<init>(LineBreaker.java:462)
at android.graphics.text.LineBreaker.<init>
at android.graphics.text.LineBreaker$Builder.build(LineBreaker.java:239)
at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:681)
at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:612)
at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:1091)
at android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.onSpanChanged(DynamicLayout.java:1126)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1321)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendToSpanWatchers(SpannableStringBuilder.java:665)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:594)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:232)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:39)
at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:376)
at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:71)
at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:485)
at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:362)
at com.facebook.react.views.textinput.c$b.onKeyDown(ReactEditText.java:1)
at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:9503)
at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:9275)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3501)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:15384)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:738)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at com.facebook.react.y.dispatchKeyEvent(ReactRootView.java:4)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1978)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:1091)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1958)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4329)
at androidx.core.app.f.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:1)
at androidx.core.view.g.e(KeyEventDispatcher.java:2)
at androidx.core.app.f.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:3)
at androidx.appcompat.app.d.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:4)
at j.i.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:1)
at androidx.appcompat.app.g$o.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:915)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7844)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7652)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7001)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7058)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7222)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7032)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7279)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:7058)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7024)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7032)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:7005)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10568)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:10456)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10412)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl(ViewRootImpl.java:6616)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:6491)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

---

Second One

```
io.sentry.android.core.ApplicationNotResponding: Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms.
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpanFlags(SpannableStringInternal.java:331)
at android.text.SpannableString.getSpanFlags(SpannableString.java:24)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:389)
at android.text.SpannableString.getSpans(SpannableString.java:24)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:434)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:563)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:521)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:39)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:945)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:219)
at com.android.internal.inputmethod.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:201)
at com.android.internal.inputmethod.RemoteInputConnectionImpl.lambda$commitText$16$com-android-internal-inputmethod-RemoteInputConnectionImpl(RemoteInputConnectionImpl.java:569)
at com.android.internal.inputmethod.RemoteInputConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda34.run
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

For the second one, I have already tried switching off auto correct in text input for samsung devices. Also not the mutable issue fixed that by adding androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1.

Comment: send terminal error

Comment: Not getting it on terminal, it’s happening on app downloaded from play store

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/786#issuecomment-598745949

Comment: This clearly doesn't fix the crash issue, it will simply remove it from tracking.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue on Samsung devices. Did you find a fix yet?

Comment: Yes, added answer below please check. The below solution worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading through a lot of github issues, the below code is temporary fix for ANR issue.
Added false for these keyboardType, autoCorrect, spellCheck

```
 <TextInput
                    value={this.state.msg}
                    placeholder="Type something here..."
                    placeholderTextColor = {Colors.placeholderColor}
                    multiline={true}
                    onChangeText={async val => {
                      await this.setState({msg: val});
                    }}
                    keyboardType={DeviceInfo?.getBrand()?.toLowerCase() === 'samsung' ? 'visible-password' : 'default'}
                    numberOfLines={ DeviceInfo?.getBrand()?.toLowerCase() === 'samsung' ? (this.state.msg.length > 50 && this.state.msg !== '' ? 3 : 1) : 1}
                    textAlignVertical='top'
                    autoCorrect={DeviceInfo?.getBrand()?.toLowerCase() !== 'samsung'}
                    // returnKeyType={DeviceInfo?.getBrand()?.toLowerCase() !== 'samsung' ? 'default' : 'none'}
                    spellCheck={DeviceInfo?.getBrand()?.toLowerCase() !== 'samsung'}
                    style={styles.chatInputField}
                  />
```